Javascript can't find certain existing element
I'm on writing a Javascript, which should find consent banner buttons and click on the buttons like "accept all cookies". My code works for multiple sites, here is it:
function removeDiacritics(text) {
    return text.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
}

function clickButtonByLabels(labels) {
    // Normalize and lower-case the labels to make the matching diacritic-insensitive and case-insensitive
    const normalizedLabels = labels.map(label => removeDiacritics(label.toLowerCase()));

    // Create an XPath expression to find buttons containing any of the specified texts
    const xpath = normalizedLabels
        .map(label => `contains(translate(normalize-space(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')), 'ÁÉÍÓÚÜÑáéíóúüñäöü', 'AEIOUUNaeiouunaou'), '${label}')`)
        .join(" or ");
    const finalXpath = `//button[${xpath}]`;

    const targetButton = document.evaluate(finalXpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;

    if (targetButton) {
        console.log(`Button with label found and clicked: ${targetButton.textContent.trim()}`);
        targetButton.click();
    } else {
        console.log('No button found with the specified labels');
    }
}

function clickButtonByTestId(testId) {
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(`button[data-testid="${testId}"]`);
    
    buttons.forEach(button => {
        console.log(`Button with test ID ${testId} found and clicked`);
        button.click();
    });

    if (buttons.length === 0) {
        console.log(`No button found with test ID ${testId}`);
    }
}

clickButtonByLabels(['Accept', 'Confirm', 'Agree', 'Aktivieren', 'akzeptieren', 'Zulassen', 'Erlauben', 'Auswählen']);

But on one site the code doesn't find needed button. The site is https://www.notebooksbilliger.de/ (run it in incognito mode to see consent banner). I tried to debug it and wrote a simple code to list all buttons with labels, like this:
function findAllButtonsWithLabels() {
    const buttons = document.evaluate("//button", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
    
    const buttonInfoArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < buttons.snapshotLength; i++) {
        const button = buttons.snapshotItem(i);
        const label = button.textContent.trim();
        buttonInfoArray.push({ element: button, label: label });
    }
    
    return buttonInfoArray;
}

const allButtonsWithLabels = findAllButtonsWithLabels();
console.log(allButtonsWithLabels);

Running it I realized, that buttons from the consent banner, like on the screenshot, are not listed.

Q: What is the problem with finding this button with //button? How can I find it?

Please don't ask us to go inspect code at a 3rd party site. Post the relevant code (HTML, CSS, and JavaScript) right here in your question.

And why are you using XPath instead of the DOM?

@ScottMarcus this is just too much code and I don't know, what special snippet of code could be relevant. Good idea with DOM. Will try. getElementByTagName?

It's actually getElementsByTagName and no, don't use that as that returns a "live" node list, which can affect performance. Use .querySelector([CSS selector]) to get the first matching node or use .querySelectorAll([CSS selector])  to get a node list of all the matching nodes.

This code must work with very different sites, so I cant relate on css. I think I dont cause performance issues, because this code must work only once. Would you in this case recommend getElementsByTagName?

You don't need to have CSS to use the two methods, you only need to pass any valid CSS selector to them. As I say, don't use getElementsByTagName. If you want to get all the elements of a certain type use .querySelectorAll("[tag name here]").

The problem was to find button located in the shadow DOM. I was misguided by different versions of the same consent solution, where one version doesn't use shadow DOM, but the other does.
Now here the working JS code, which finds multiple labels in English and German of an "accept all cookies" buttons, supports diacritic characters in labels and finds buttons in the shadow DOM.
Surely I'm thankful for any improvements. Feel free to extend.
function removeDiacritics(text) {
    return text.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
}

function findButtonByLabels(labels) {
    // Normalize and lower-case the labels to make the matching diacritic-insensitive and case-insensitive
    const normalizedLabels = labels.map(label => removeDiacritics(label.toLowerCase()));

    // Method 1: XPath approach
    const xpath = normalizedLabels
        .map(label => `contains(translate(normalize-space(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')), 'ÁÉÍÓÚÜÑáéíóúüñäöü', 'AEIOUUNaeiouunaou'), '${label}')`)
        .join(" or ");
    const finalXpath = `//button[${xpath}]`;
    const targetButtonByXPath = document.evaluate(finalXpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;

    // Method 2: Shadow DOM approach
    let targetButtonByShadowDOM;
    const elementsWithShadowDOM = document.querySelectorAll("*");
    elementsWithShadowDOM.forEach(element => {
        if (element.shadowRoot) {
            const shadowRoot = element.shadowRoot;
            const buttonsInShadowDOM = shadowRoot.querySelectorAll("button");
            buttonsInShadowDOM.forEach(button => {
                if (normalizedLabels.some(label => button.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(label))) {
                    targetButtonByShadowDOM = button;
                    return;
                }
            });
        }
    });

    // Return the first button found by either method
    return targetButtonByXPath || targetButtonByShadowDOM;
}

function clickButtonByLabels(labels) {
    const targetButton = findButtonByLabels(labels);

    if (targetButton) {
        console.log(`Button with label found and clicked: ${targetButton.textContent.trim()}`);
        targetButton.click();
    } else {
        console.log('No button found with the specified labels');
    }
}

// Example usage with diacritic and case insensitivity
clickButtonByLabels(['Accept', 'Confirm', 'Agree', 'Aktivieren', 'Akzeptieren', 'Zulassen', 'Erlauben', 'Auswählen']);

